# Cannot read property 'api' of undefined - what does that mean?

Tags: php, content-management-system, headless, directus

I just tried install Directus locally. I created account and when I want to sign in I see error "Cannot read property 'api' of undefined". When I was installing Directus there werent any errors. Whats problem and how to fix it?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: do you have a /data/config volume?

Answer (score 0):

That means that your API is undefined so it cannot read it's properties.
Dependency issue most likely.

Comment: I installed all via composer, still same error .____.

Comment: @MuteSummer Well this is a great opportunity for you to find out why this error occurs by digging into the code and checking if you can find anything that's missing. The easy way to fix it is to delete your composer file and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error as you. Did you set the Directus project name to "admin"?
Reinstall and set it to something else and it will work.